# Match multiple patterns in any order (Perl)

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file that looks like (but a LOT bigger):

```
arbstring1014: 120|PROKKA_00511 630|PROKKA_01218 630|PROKKA_01999 630|PROKKA_00506
arbstring1015: 120|PROKKA_02025 630|PROKKA_03113 120|PROKKA_02363 196|PROKKA_02308
arbstring1016: 120|PROKKA_02059 196|PROKKA_03630 630|PROKKA_03589 630|PROKKA_00462
arbstring1017: 120|PROKKA_02961 196|PROKKA_03061 630|PROKKA_03283 120|PROKKA_03099
arbstring1025: 120|PROKKA_02979 196|PROKKA_02928 630|PROKKA_03158
arbstring1026: 120|PROKKA_00924 196|PROKKA_00857 630|PROKKA_00906
arbstring1027: 120|PROKKA_02739 196|PROKKA_02684 630|PROKKA_02848
arbstring1028: 120|PROKKA_01415 196|PROKKA_01350 630|PROKKA_01503
arbstring1029: 120|PROKKA_03195 196|PROKKA_03175 630|PROKKA_03374
arbstring1030: 120|PROKKA_03050 196|PROKKA_03001 630|PROKKA_03230
```

I want to find rows that have all of these before the "PROKKA_XXXXX":

```
120|
196|
630|
```

The following script will find them but seemingly only in the order in which they're written in the script (eg. only returns a row with 196|, 120|, 630| when I know for a fact there are rows with all three in, but in a different order):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w use strict; use warnings;

#get genes that are present in all groups  from a groups.txt

#scans through output of orthomcl to get genes that are only core open (IN,"<$ARGV[0]")  or die $!;

while (my $line = <IN>) {
#change the VS1 to match your unique phage ID add "& ($line =~m/VS11\|/)" to add more rules to match . will need 15 for 15 phage if ($line =~ m/196\|/gi && $line =~ m/120\|/gi && $line =~
m/630\|/gi)#(=~m/120\|/gi))#($line =~m/196\|/gi)

#if (/(?=.*re1)(?=.*re2)(?=.*re3)/s)

#& ($line =~m/630\|/) & ($line =~m/120\|/)   #& ($line =~m/IME1\|/) #&
#($line =~m/KBNP\|/) & ($line =~m/LUZ7\|/) & ($line =~m/PA26\|/) & ($line =~m/RLP1\|/) & ($line =~m/VC01\|/) &
#($line =~m/DSS3\|/)  & ($line =~m/EcP1\|/)  & ($line =~m/G7C\|/) & ($line =~m/JA1\|/) & ($line =~m/LIT1\|/) &
#($line =~m/N4\|/) & ($line =~m/pS6\|/) & ($line =~m/RPP1\|/) & ($line =~m/VBP3\|/) & ($line =~m/VBP4\|/) &
#($line =~m/058\|/)  &  ($line =~m/076\|/)  &  ($line =~m/JWA\|/)  &  ($line =~m/JWD\|/) & ($line =~m/PRES\|/)    { print $line ; } }
```

Any help with this would be brilliant as I've looked around a fair bit already...

Comment: So what the final output you require ?

Comment: I wasn't very clear with that was I, apologies.

I want just the rows that contain all three (120|, 630|, 196|) any number of times. There are some rows that have only 1 or 2 of them and they need to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would propose using a look-ahead:

```
^
(?=.*120\|PROKKA_\d+)
(?=.*196\|PROKKA_\d+)
(?=.*630\|PROKKA_\d+)
.*
```

[regex101.com demo](http://regex101.com/r/oM8aH0/1)

(this is broken across multiple lines for readability only). Starting at the beginning of each line, look ahead for all 3 of your criteria: 120, 196, and 630. If they are found, the `.*` will match that line.

Comment: That worked exactly as I expected and matches my test file I made by changing the order in the script for each run. 

Thank you so much! I've never even heard of a look ahead before...

Answer (score 0):

The code you pasted there has the answer and even explains it in a comment, except that it is screwed up.

What you pasted:

```
while (my $line = <IN>) {
#change the VS1 to match your unique phage ID add "& ($line =~m/VS11\|/)" to add more rules to match . will need 15 for 15 phage if ($line =~ m/196\|/gi && $line =~ m/120\|/gi && $line =~
m/630\|/gi)#(=~m/120\|/gi))#($line =~m/196\|/gi)
```

doesn't make any sense.  What appears to be intended is something like:

```
while (my $line = <IN>) {
# change the numbers, which are phage IDs;
# e.g., to match your unique phage ID, say 196, add:
#   && ($line =~ m/196\|/)
#
  if ($line =~ m/196\|/gi && $line =~ m/120\|/gi && $line =~ m/630\|/gi)) {
```

then comes the code to execute in case `$line` matches those three, and  after the code,
the `if` and `while` clauses must be closed:

```
  }
}
```

This could be made more readable, but we'd need the full script for that.